# Mocking a MongooseModule import in Nestjs tests

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I'm experimenting with NestJs, following a tutorial. I've decided I want to write some tests on the code I've written.

I'm writing tests for the `ProductController` and the test file for the controller mocks the `ProductModule` to which the controller belongs. My `ProductModule` imports `MongooseModule` and presumably I need to mock that import in the `TestingModule` of the controller test file.

How can I go about mocking that import?

ProductModule;

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductController } from './product.controller';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ProductSchema } from './schemas/product.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Product', schema: ProductSchema }]),
  ],
  providers: [ProductService],
  controllers: [ProductController],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

ProductController test file;

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ProductController } from './product.controller';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

describe('ProductController', () => {
  let controller: ProductController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [ProductService],
      controllers: [ProductController],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<ProductController>(ProductController);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `ProductController` test I'd use a custom provider like

```js
{
  provide: ProductService,
  useValue: {
    method1: jest.fn(),
    methodN: jest.fn()
  }
}
```

For your `ProductService` test I'd mock the `@InjectModel('Product')` by using `getModelToken()` and a custom provider like

```js
{
  provide: getModelToken('Product'),
  useValue: {
    productModelMethod1: jest.fn(),
  }
}
```

[You can see a repo here with a bunch of test examples](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

Comment: Thankyou - It'd eb great to see come working examples; I'll check that repo in a bit